# Syntax deploy a library to Weblogic 10.3.6 with WLST

Tags: weblogic, weblogic-10.x, wlst

I have been trying to deploy the `jstl-1.1.2` deployable library to my Weblogic 10.3.6 with via WLST and can't get it to deploy as a `library`.

I have searched the internet and every place I find that lists how to pass in the `options` to the `deploy()` function differently.

Oracle's documentation is extremely un-helpful as well.

Below is the *most recent* post I found about this using Google and it doesn't work:

```
connect('weblogic', 'weblogic1')

edit()
startEdit()

deploy('jstl-1.1.2', path='/opt/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/common/deployable-libraries/jstl-1.1.2.war', libraryModule='true')
save()
activate()
```

I have also tried the following syntax that is suggested to work; it doesn't:

```
options = {}
options.setdefault("libraryModule", "true")
deploy('jstl-1.1.2', path='/opt/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/common/deployable-libraries/jstl-1.1.2.war', **options)
```

I have tried `libraryModule=true` and `libraryModule='true'` and `libraryModule="true"` and none of them work; they all cause the `deploy` command to not do anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Finally found an incantation that works!

This is the only syntax that I was able to get to work, which is declaring all the named parameters.

```
progress=deploy(appName='jstl', path='/opt/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/common/deployable-libraries/jstl-1.1.2.war', targets='AdminServer,', libraryModule='true')
```

Comment: deploy is for online deployments, any idea how to deploy shared libraries offline?